# Reserving space with fseek safe?

Tags: c, io, cross-platform, fseek

If you can guarantee that there is data to be written after seeking, is it safe to use `fseek` to reserve bytes at the beginning of a file? For example:

```
// reserve space
fseek(f, 4096, SEEK_SET);

// ...

// write some data after the reserved space
fwrite(buf, 1, bufsize, f);

// go back to the reserved space (to update it)
rewind(f);

// ...
```

I noticed it works on Windows, but what about other platforms? Are there any gotchas to look out for?

Comment: It doesn't reserve space on Unix. Nothing actually happens to the file until you write and flush the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this works fine. As long as you've opened the file in `w` or `w+` mode, rather than `a` or `a+`, you can seek to any point in the file and write there, and it will write at that point in the file. Other parts of the file will be left unchanged; if they were never written, they'll contain zero bytes.

So if you do the following on a file that was just opened in `w` mode (which truncates the file first):

```
fseek(f, 10, SEEK_SET);
fwrite("abc", 1, 3, f);
rewind(f);
fwrite("1234567890", 1, 10, f);
```

the contents of the file will be:

```
1234567890abc
```

Comment: Oh, dang, good point about the disk capacity. I guess I'll make `fwrite` the standard in the future then.

Comment: I assumed checking disk capacity was the whole reason. What else does it mean to "reserve" space?

Comment: I am reserving space for a file format header which I need to update later.

Comment: What do you mean by "reserving"? To me that means making sure that the space is available, and can't be taken away by something else.

Comment: By "reserve" I'm talking about putting a fixed-size block of data somewhere in the file, so that it can be updated (overwritten) later in the program, without having to re-write the whole file sequentially. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: That works fine, why wouldn't it? That's the whole point of using `fseek()`, to be able to write at different places in the file, rather than writing sequentially.

Comment: As long as you don't open the file in append mode. That forces all writes to the end of the file, so seeking has no effect on writes.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm trying to find out (if it "works fine"). I know there are differences in I/O operations between OSes, and I'm not sure if using `fseek` in this manner works on *all* OSes. So anyway, does that mean you misunderstood the original question? Do you need to update your answer?